# I am not getting any user data from google fit into android app

Tags: android, google-fit

I am trying to develop android app which will bring user fitness data(daily Step Count) from google fit.  i got below code from google fit History Api sample example. Also please tell where to put Oauth Clientid in android studio project.Below code always give step count 0.
Also in log i always get this message "Firebase app initialisation unsuccessful"

`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private static final int GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
    .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
    .build();

    if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
        this, // your activity
        GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
        GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
        fitnessOptions);
    } else {
        accessGoogleFit();
    }

}


private void accessGoogleFit() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    long endtime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    long starttime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(starttime, endtime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataSet>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DataSet dataSet) {
                    Log.d("Status","Success");
                    long total = dataSet.isEmpty()
                                    ? 0
                                    : dataSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
                    Log.d("Steps",String.valueOf(total));

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Status","Failure",e);
                }
            })
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSet>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSet> task) {
                    Log.d("Status","Complete");

                }
            });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            accessGoogleFit();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you included the uses-permission INTERNET in your Manifest?@amit patil

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code and it works fine. I think it has more to do with your configuration.

You will get 0 steps if you havent added the client_secret to your res folder.

If you navigate to your console [where you made your OAuth V2 token](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient) go here:

[Where to download JSON client_secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5LCM.png)

Then paste your client_secret inside your resource folder here:

[Where to paste OAuth Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVzPy.png)

If you still have issues with getting 0 steps, consider installing the Google Fit App and manually add steps that way. This way you can check if its an authentication problem or direct issue related to your data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, i was getting 0 steps because i was running this code on emulator which does not support google play services.

Comment: Feel free to upvote if you feel like this answer helped you @amit